# google-cloud-speech Transcription for the AAC encoding

Tags: android, ios, aac, google-cloud-speech, transcription

The question / request to the Google Speech API Team:  Would it be possible for Google Speech to provide transcription for the AAC encoding?

Background --- We are working on a mobile app that will run on iOS and Android platforms. AAC is the only encoding supported on both these platforms. Being able to get a transcription from Google for the AAC encoding is important for performance and cost reasons. We would like to avoid the step of converting the AAC encoding to a Google supported encoding.

The purpose of using the lossy encoding is to have smaller audio files -- important for efficient use of storage, memory and bandwidth resources. Since AAC is the only encoding available on both iOS and Android, it will be extremely helpful if Google speech could support the AAC encoding.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics discusses all the encodings that Google Speech API provides transcription for. Hoping that Google Speech team will add AAC encoding to the list.

Summary -- we need to send AAC encoding to Google Speech API and get the transcription for this encoding. If anyone from the Google Speech team is reading this post, I would appreciate a response --- is the Speech team planning on adding AAC encoding to the list of supported encodings in cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics ?

Answer (score 0):

> *We are working on a mobile app...*

Your app should use the API to transcribe the audio. The Android SDK can decompress your AAC data into raw digital audio (PCM). If you must provide `.wav` to the API, then simply make a 44-byte header for the PCM in the style of WAVE format. Put everything (header + PCM data) into a bytearray and feed to the API.

AAC is not audio. It is compression math that must be decoded to recover back the PCM (wave) audio data. You may be storing AAC *`"for efficient use of storage, memory..."`* but the device is still playing a *(temporary)* large Wave file held in the RAM of that device.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in acknowledging your response. Thank you for the suggestion. However, this approach does not meet our requirements.   We need to send AAC encoding to Google Speech API and get the transcription for this encoding. If anyone from the Google Speech team is reading this, I would appreciate a response --- is the Speech team planning on adding AAC encoding to the list of supported encodings in https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics ?